# Java calendar date logical error

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm trying to find out if a date is between two specific dates or not. I'm using the Calendar library to represent the dates. My code:

```
public static void double getnumber(Calendar cal){

Calendar cred1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cred2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    cred1.set(Calendar.JANUARY, 21, 2012);
    cred2.set(Calendar.FEBRUARY, 8, 2012);

    if(cal.after(cred1) && cal.before(cred2)){ 
    System.out.println("case 1");
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("case 2");
    }

}
```

The date I'm testing is this:

```
    Calendar test = Calendar.getInstance();
    test.set(Calendar.JANUARY, 25, 2012);
    getnumber(test);
```

My problem is that when I test that date, the application always print "Case 2" when it's supposed to print "Case 1". Any ideas why? Any help is much appreciated, as I've tried everything but nothing seems to work, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The javadoc of Calendar.set(int, int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29) says:

```
public final void set(int year,
                  int month,
                  int date)
Sets the values for the fields year, month, and date.
```

You set month - day - year : which is not the right order

Comment: ye waiting for 15minutes to pass mate ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's why: this is the method of Calendar.set

```
public final void set(int year, int month, int date)
    {
        set(YEAR, year);
        set(MONTH, month);
        set(DATE, date);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the arguments to `set` the wrong way around. See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29).